# A bounded function with no limit at $x=1$

Tags: limits, functions

What could be considered a bounded function with no limit at $x=1$?

I came up with $f(x)=0$ if $x<1$, 1 if $x>=1$. Is this correct? Are there other examples?

Comment: Maybe try $f(x) = \dfrac{\sin x}{x-1}$?

Comment: That's not bounded, @algevristis

Comment: $f(x)=\sin\frac1{x-1}$ when $x\neq 1$ and $f(1)=0.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my apologies

Comment: The floor function, $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is another example.

Comment: The floor function is not bounded on $\mathbb{R}$